# wouldn't he like that?

Tags: negation, interrogatives

Can I use

> a. Can I send Tom's article to my wife to read, or wouldn't he like that?

instead of

> b. Can I send Tom's article to my wife to read, or would he not like that?

?

I know (b) is correct, but I don't know why I don't like (a).

If (a) can be used, does it mean exactly the same as (b)?

Comment: (a) is just a less formal way of expressing (b).

Comment: I would parse "wouldn't he like that" as "he would like that", similar to any other sentences phrased as questions in the negative ("isn't it pretty", "don't you think", etc) and therefore it sounds strange to me. However, I can imagine someone using it with the meaning you intend.

Comment: @Esther - But surely not if it's preceded by **or**, which implies a reason for not sending it?

Comment: @KateBunting I would read/think twice and figure out what it means, but to me (native AmE speaker), it sounds confusing the first time. Spoken it probably would be less confusing, but written I would probably need to read it twice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference. Negative questions are usually used for rhetorical purposes and not simply to request information in a neutral way. For example, if you eat a large meal and I ask "have you had enough?", then I am simply requesting information in a neutral way.<sup>1</sup> On the other hand, if I ask "haven't you had enough?", then I am suggesting that you have, in fact, had enough. The contraction is perfectly normal in this case.

However, you're asking an "actual" question and not a rhetorical one. The contraction doesn't work so well in that case. (Keep in mind that opinions on this will differ and that there may be differences among various dialects, too.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It's possible to ask this question in a non-neutral way through context, intonation, etc. That's a separate issue, though.